# ViewPager showing preloaded fragment instead of current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using Tablayout(android.support.design.widget.TabLayout) with ViePager instantiating 4 fragments to FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

When i scroll through all the fragments are loaded perfectly.But when i select a tab randomly pre-loaded fragment(I know that view pager instantiate neighbor fragments along current fragment) is shown instead of current fragment.

[In my case when i click 3rd tab fragment in 4th position is being shown,same fragment is shown in 4th position too].

How can i correct this situation.
Thanks in advance.

Adapter

```
public class OrderStatusAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public OrderStatusAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitles.add(title);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
}

}
```

ViewPager

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
          viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
          tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.orderStatusTabs);
          tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
          tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
          tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                            }
                        });
          }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    OrderStatusAdapter adapter = new OrderStatusAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(FailedFragment.newInstance(list1, title), "Category 1");
    adapter.addFragment(FailedFragment.newInstance(list2, title), "Category 2");
    adapter.addFragment(FailedFragment.newInstance(list3, title),       "Category 3");
    adapter.addFragment(FailedFragment.newInstance(list4, title),       "Category 4");

    }
```

Comment: You'll need to provide your code. Sounds like you have an off by one error with your tab positions vs the viewer pager positions.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you are calling your `viewPager.setAdapter()` twice, once in `setupViewPager()` and once after that.

Comment: Where do you add the tabs to the `TabLayout`?  Also, you're not creating an instance of `OrderedAdapter` and setting it to be the `ViewPager`'s adapter.

Comment: I modified the code snippet...i am not adding any tabs here.Instead iam setting tablayout to viewpager `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` @LarrySchiefer

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail when skimming the code. When you use `.setupWithViewPager()` a `OnTabSelectedListener()` is automatically created for you and hooked up: [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)).  Since you're hooking up your own listener, you're actually doing more work than you need.  The `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` look to be using different position information and the auto-listener does the mapping correctly.

Comment: initially i was with default setup and i got this problem so i tried to implement my own OnTabSelectedListener()....it didn't work either.@LarrySchiefer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all because of RecycleView Custom adapter whose instance is not being destroyed and so the previous data is being loaded.So i shifted the adapter inside the fragment and it does the trick.